# Cairo fill area between two rectangles

Tags: graphics, cairo

In my program I want to fill the area between two rectangles with some color and inner rectangle should be white. the way I am doing it is draw outer rectangle and fill it with desired color, then draw inner rectangle and fill it with white color.

something like following:

```c
cairo_rectangle(cr, x1, y1, width1, height1);  
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr,0,0,0);  
cairo_fill(cr);  
cairo_rectangle(cr, x2, y2, width2, height2);  
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr,1,1,1);  
cairo_fill(cr);
```

I am wondering if there is any other way of doing this where I can draw both the rectangle and then fill the area between them?

Comment: Which version of cairo? It likely doesn't matter, but just in case.

Comment: @oliverseal its 1.12.16

Comment: Upon re-reading your question, I pulled my answer. Why not just stroke the thickness you want and then fill? I assume you're trying to reduce the fills and set_source_rgb calls since they're expensive.

Comment: @oliverseal I can do that but if I have two or three or shapes inside one another, will this work?

Comment: I don't think so. Depends on the desired visual. If you have multiple colors, it's going to require `cairo_set_source_rgb` and `cairo_fill` for each.

Answer (score 0):

```
cairo_rectangle(cr, x1, y1, width1, height1);
cairo_rectangle(cr, x2, y2, width2, height2);
/* Remember to reset this to CAIRO_FILL_RULE_WINDINIG if it matters for other code */
cairo_set_fill_rule(cr, CAIRO_FILL_RULE_EVEN_ODD);
cairo_fill(cr);
```

Comment: I am not aware of cairo_set_fill_rule(). I read about it in cairo manual but did not understand well. In case of CAIRO_FILL_RULE_EVEN_ODD - manual says if total number of intersections is odd, the point will be filled. Could you please tell me how it will work in my case?

Comment: This was my original thought, too, but upon re-reading, this doesn't solve it.

Comment: @sap: In your case, the winding for pixels inside the inner rectangle will be two, because it is contained in both rectangles. Since this is even, the inner rectangle won't be included. Points between both rectangles only have a winding of one and thus will be included in the fill. So this should solve the "fill the area between them"-part of your question. I am not sure what you mean with "draw both the rectangle. Perhaps you want cairo_fill_preserve(cr); cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, other_color); cairo_stroke(cr);?

Comment: @UliSchlachter By "draw both rectangle" i meant that instead of doing cairo_set_source_rgb() and cairo_fill() for each rectangle, is there any other way. After your explanation, now I understood your solution. I will give it a try. Thanks